# why C# does not provide internal helper for passing property as reference?

Tags: c#

### This is issue about LANGUAGE DESIGN.

Please do not answer to the question until you read entire post! Thank you.

With all helpers existing in C# (like lambdas, or automatic properties) it is very odd for me that I cannot pass property by a reference. Let's say I would like to do that:

```
foo(ref my_class.prop);
```

I get error so I write instead:

```
{
   var tmp = my_class.prop;
   foo(tmp);
   my_class.prop = tmp;
}
```

And now it works. But please notice two things:

1. it is general template, I didn't put anywhere type, only "var", so it applies for all types and number of properties I have to pass
2. I have to do it over and over again, with no benefit -- it is mechanical work

The existing problem actually kills such useful functions as Swap. Swap is normally 3 lines long, but since it takes 2 references, calling it takes 5 lines. Of course it is nonsense and I simply write "swap" by hand each time I would like to call it. But this shows C# prevents reusable code, bad.

### THE QUESTION

So -- what bad could happen if compiler automatically create temporary variables (as I do by hand), call the function, and assign the values back to properties? Is this any danger in it? I don't see it so I am curious what do you think why the design of this issue looks like it looks now.

Cheers,

**EDIT** As 280Z28 gave great examples for beating idea of automatically wrapping ref for properties I still think wrapping properties with temporary variables would be useful. Maybe something like this:

```
Swap(inout my_class.prop1,inout my_class.prop2);
```

Otherwise no real Swap for C# :-(

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000654.html

Comment: and indexers! I hate this! These features seem like they're not first class in the language :\ In my opinion, this is a plain language design mistake - makes things like a _fully general_ swap impossible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of assumptions you can make about the meaning and behavior of a `ref` parameter. For example,

Case 1:

```
int x;
Interlocked.Increment(ref x);
```

If you could pass a property by ref to this method, the call would be the same but it would *completely* defeat the semantics of the method.

Case 2:

```
void WaitForCompletion(ref bool trigger)
{
    while (!trigger)
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Summary: A by-ref parameter passes the address of a memory location to the function. An implementation creating a temporary variable in order to "pass a property by reference" would be semantically equivalent to passing by value, which is precisely the behavior that you're disallowing when you make the parameter a `ref` one.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that. It seems that it should be some other keyword to wrapping property, something like:

foo(in out my_class.prop);

Comment: @macias: One possibility is to write it so you can go `my_class.prop = foo(my_class.prop);`

Answer (score 4):

Your proposal is called "copy in - copy out" reference semantics. Copy-in-copy-out semantics are subtly different from what we might call "ref to variable" semantics; different enough to be confusing and wrong in many situations. Others have already given you some examples; there are plenty more. For example:

```
void M() { F(ref this.p); }
void F(ref int x) { x = 123; B(); }
void B() { Console.WriteLine(this.p); }
```

If "this.p" is a property, with your proposal, this prints the *old* value of the property. If it is a field then it prints the *new* value.

Now imagine that you refactor a field to be a property. In the real language, that causes errors if you were passing a field by ref; the problem is brought to your attention. With your proposal, there is no error; instead, behaviour changes silently and subtly.  That makes for bugs.

Consistency is important in C#, particularly in parts of the language that people find confusing, like reference semantics. I would want either references to *always* be copy-in-copy-out or *never* copy-in-copy-out. Doing it one way sometimes and another way other times seems like really bad design for C#, a language which values consistency over brevity.

Comment: "VB.Net removes this inconsistency and allows properties to be passes by reference. This is implemented under the hood by means of temporary variable."
http://blogs.msdn.com/vbteam/archive/2010/01/26/the-many-cases-of-byref.aspx

Comment: Great answer, and great comment -- thank you both. Now, I've heard that in time VB and C# should be more alike, i.e. features one has should go to the other :-)

Comment: VB and C# have different design principles. VB designers value "just make it work the way the user thinks it should, even if that means adding unusual inconsistencies and special cases". C# designers value a clear, consistent programming model even if that means making you write longer code to express exactly what you mean. Both approaches are valid and reasonable; if you are the sort of programmer who agrees more with the former approach, consider switching to VB.

Answer (score 1):

Because a property is a method.  It is a language construct responding to a pattern of encapsulating the setting and retrieval of a private field through a set of methods.  It is functionally equivalent to this:

```
class Foo
{
    private int _bar;
    public int GetBar( ) { return _bar; }
    public void SetBar( ) { _bar = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a ref argument, changes to the underlying variable will be observed by the method, this won't happen in your case. In other words, it is not exactly the same.

Comment: I believe you are referring to what I put as Case 2 in my method which specifically has bad implications in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: Doesn't even have to be multi-threaded. The property might be the the value of a temperature sensor, queried every time the property is accessed. Strictly single-threaded (unless you consider the real world a separate thread of course)

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = obj.prop;
foo(ref t);
obj.prop = t;
```

Here, side effects of getter and setter are only visible once each, regardless of how many times the "by-ref" parameter got assigned to.

Imagine a dynamically computed property. Its value might change at any time. With this construct, `foo` is not kept up to date **even though the code suggests this** ("I'm passing the property to the method")

Comment: The question the OP asked is quite literally "Why does the compiler not implement a property as a ref parameter by {insert your code snippet}."

Comment: "what bad could happen if compiler automatically create temporary variables [..]? Is this any danger in it?" That's what I answered.

Answer (score 0):

> So -- what bad could happen if
>   compiler automatically create
>   temporary variables (as I do by hand),
>   call the function, and assign the
>   values back to properties? Is this any
>   danger in it?

The danger is that the compiler is doing something you don't know. Making the code confusing because properties are methods, not variables.

Comment: Given what the compiler does to implement `yield return`, I'm not convinced this specific argument is relevant to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide just one simple example where it would cause confusion. Assume it was possible (as is in VB):

```
class Weird {
   public int Prop { get; set; }
}

static void Test(ref int x) {
   x = 42;
   throw new Exception();
}

static void Main() { 
   int v = 10;
   try {
      Test(ref v);
   } catch {}
   Console.WriteLine(v); // prints 42

   var c = new Weird();
   c.Prop = 10;
   try {
      Test(ref c.Prop);
   } catch {}
   Console.WriteLine(c.Prop); // prints 10!!!
}
```

Nice. Isn't it?

Comment: I don't know how about VB, but adding finally in auto-generated helper is not a such big deal, so it would print 42 as well.

Comment: @macias: it's not as easy as it seems. Assume you pass a couple properties and they throw exception in setters. The number of exceptions thrown can add up. You can't catch all of them and throw a single one.

Answer (score -1):

Because, as Eric Lippert is fond of pointing out, every language feature must be understood, designed, specified, implemented, tested and documented. And it's obviously not a common scenario/pain point.

Comment: This case is well understood such that it can't go on to the other points. This is not an example of limited developer resources.

Comment: @280Z28 - You say that, and yet in other .Net languages (e.g. VB) you can certainly circumvent some of these expectations, such as passing a literal as a ref argument, and the compiler happily nodding and agreeing with it. So it *might* be an area that someone might want to explore. I was giving a more general answer since the OP was insisting that this was a language design question.

Comment: But even then it's a comment, not really an answer.