# Why tracking reference does not assign a value to the referenced object?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, tracking-reference

I do not understand why the tracking reference is not doing its job when passed variable is on the heap. Here is the code:

```
ref class DataContainer
    {
    public:
        property DateTime Time;
    };

DataContainer^ dc = gcnew DataContainer ();
DateTime timeOnStack;
// first call with output variable on the stack
bool timeParsed = DateTime::TryParseExact ("20160104132500184", "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff", CultureInfo::InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles::None, timeOnStack);
// second call with output variable on the heap
timeParsed = DateTime::TryParseExact ("20160104132500184", "yyyyMMddHHmmssfff", CultureInfo::InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles::None, (dc->Time));
```

First `TryParseExact` call which uses locally initialized variable `timeOnStack` to put parsed DateTime value works as expected and sets parsed date correctly: call `timeOnStack.ToString ()` returns `"1/4/2016 1:25:00 PM"`
While the second one even it returns `true` it doesn't set correct value to `dc->Time`: call `dc->Time.ToString ()` returns `"1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"`

What I am not seeing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a tracking reference (`ref` in C#) is passing the address of the local storage for an object, rather than passing the object. However, `dc->Time` in your example is not a local variable, or a field, it's a property. Remember that under the hood, properties are getter/setter method pairs. What you have here is the equivalent to `dc->GetTime()`.

The compiler is taking your method call, and passing the result of that method call as a tracking reference. There is no assignment of that back to the property; that's not how it works. The temporary local variable that received the result of the method call and was passed as a tracking reference is not available.

If you try this in C#, you'll get an error `A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter.` C++/CLI allows this to go through, though probably not as you intended.

The compiler could choose to implement some syntactic sugar: Call the property getter, assign to temporary variable, then call the setter. However, both C# and C++/CLI have chosen not to implement that, for good reasons: see [why C# does not provide internal helper for passing property as reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2182455/480937).